# Colorbox inside iFrame - Close from parent

Tags: iframe, colorbox

I am working on a project where I am simply loading same directory content into an iFrame. No external pages.

I have Colorbox within the iFrame content which is working beautifully.

My question is: I have some "parent" buttons which I would like to make them close any of the iFrame Colorbox popups. The project is an "information point" system with some buttons in the parent that show at all times, but whenever I click the buttons the iFrame Colorbox stays open.

A lot of the pages I have found talk from the opposite way, controlling the parent from within a Colorbox iFrame...

I'm going to guess that this may not be achievable from a security point of view...

many thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery the other way round so the child controls the parent and hides the parent controls and when the ColorBox control is closed it "shows" the parent controls.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
$('.cboxIframe')[0].contentWindow().$.colorbox.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, I tried this but it still didn't work unfortunately. To complete this I ended up using jQuery the other way round so the child controls the parent and hides the parent controls and when the ColorBox control is closed it "shows" the parent controls.